# how to make bootstrap table clickable

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap like this in main.html page:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
 <thead>
    <tr>
     <th scope="col">#</th>
     <th scope="col">First</th>
     <th scope="col">Last</th>
     <th scope="col">Handle</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">1</th>
    <td>Mark</td>
    <td>Otto</td>
    <td>@mdo</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <th scope="row">2</th>
   <td>Jacob</td>
   <td>Thornton</td>
   <td>@fat</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th scope="row">3</th>
  <td>Larry</td>
  <td>the Bird</td>
  <td>@twitter</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

My requirement is:

- When I click on any row of the table( either on the text or even in the space between two columns) it has to redirect to another Html page.

how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using jQuery. Bind an event listener on click of TR and then redirect the user as needed.

Your HTML

```
<table class="table table-striped">
 <thead>
    <tr>
     <th scope="col">#</th>
     <th scope="col">First</th>
     <th scope="col">Last</th>
     <th scope="col">Handle</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">1</th>
    <td>Mark</td>
    <td>Otto</td>
    <td>@mdo</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <th scope="row">2</th>
   <td>Jacob</td>
   <td>Thornton</td>
   <td>@fat</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th scope="row">3</th>
  <td>Larry</td>
  <td>the Bird</td>
  <td>@twitter</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

jQuery Code

```
$(function() {
  $('tr').on('click', function() {
    document.location.href = 'https://google.com';

  });
});
```

Plain JavaScript

```
var table = document.getElementById('js-table');
for(var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
  table.rows[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.location.href = "https://google.com"
  });
}
```

Comment: can we do it with javascript

Comment: sure. I have edited the answer and added code for it.

Comment: You will need to add a id to your table.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport"
              content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table class="table table-striped" id="tableId">
     <thead>
        <tr>
         <th scope="col">#</th>
         <th scope="col">First</th>
         <th scope="col">Last</th>
         <th scope="col">Handle</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <th scope="row">2</th>
       <td>Jacob</td>
       <td>Thornton</td>
       <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

    <script>
        function addRowHandlers() {
            var table = document.getElementById("tableId");
            var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
            for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                var currentRow = table.rows[i];
                var createClickHandler = 
                    function(row) 
                    {
                        return function() { 
                                                var cell = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
                                                var id = cell.innerHTML;
                                                alert("id:" + id);
                                                window.location.href = "http://www.w3schools.com";
                                         };
                    };

                currentRow.onclick = createClickHandler(currentRow);
            }
        }
        window.onload = addRowHandlers();
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this by using Javascript on tr (inline)  :

```
<tr onclick="document.location = 'links.html';">
```

In this way you can set different links for different rows. Please check below updated HTML snippet :

```
<table class="table table-striped">
 <thead>
    <tr>
     <th scope="col">#</th>
     <th scope="col">First</th>
     <th scope="col">Last</th>
     <th scope="col">Handle</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr onclick="document.location = 'http://www.google.com';">
    <th scope="row">1</th>
    <td>Mark</td>
    <td>Otto</td>
    <td>@mdo</td>
 </tr>
 <tr onclick="document.location = 'http://www.himanshu.com';">
   <th scope="row">2</th>
   <td>Jacob</td>
   <td>Thornton</td>
   <td>@fat</td>
</tr>
<tr onclick="document.location = '/links.html';">
  <th scope="row">3</th>
  <td>Larry</td>
  <td>the Bird</td>
  <td>@twitter</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find below the code that will redirect you to another link on click of any rows (except header row)

Add click event on all the rows inside the table body and execute your task.

```js
$(function() {
  $('tbody tr').click(function() {
    window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com';
  })
})
```

)

Answer (score 0):

First, i suggest to add class to `<tr>` tag (so if you plan to have multiple tables in page it does not affect other table)

Then, i assume your using jquery and you have dynamic table rows.

```
#.link is the class <tr class="link" data-href="https://google.com">...</tr>
#:not(a) => added this so you can add other link `<a>` to your row (remove it if not needed...)

// same page redirect
$(document).on('click', 'tr.link:not(a)', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation(); // only add this if you have <a> tag in row
  window.location.href = $(this).data('href'); // dynamic link
});

// new tab redirect
$(document).on('click', 'tr.link', function(){
  $('<a href="'+ $(this).attr('data-href') +'" target="_blank">External Link</a>')[0].click();
});
```